# Which Stack Exchange site should I post a question about certificate providers to?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

https://superuser.com/q/571905/172193

That was closed as being off topic. In my mind it ''does'' "relate to computer software" just as much as such questions as "What's a good free GUI zip client for Windows" or some such.

If superuser.com isn't the place to ask that question… where is the appropriate place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, "what's a good free GUI zip client for windows" is a quite bad question for Super User and would probably be closed rather fast, as it's not constructive and asking for a product recommendation.

Your question isn't asking about computer software or hardware—it's asking about providers for certificates, and it's basically a shopping question, which would be off topic for the entire Stack Exchange network of sites. See: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)